# Condition to not use part of code in build.gradle when building debug

Tags: android

Hey guys I have a config inside of android/app/build.gradle

```
configurations.all {
  resolutionStrategy {
    force "com.facebook.soloader:soloader:0.8.0"
  }
}
```

which I only need when building release. When I build debug this code crashes the app so I have to remove it and not commit it every time I'm developing. Is there a way to exclude this when building debug. Thanks